# How to get Decimal division remainder in python3?

Tags: python, decimal

I looking for a pythonic way to get the remainder of a Decimal division.

My use case here is I want to dispatch one price on several products. For example, I got an order of 10$ with 3 items, and I want to dispatch the price on the 3 products without loosing any cents :)

And because it is a price, I want only 2 decimals.

So far here is the solution I found :

```
from decimal import Decimal

twoplaces = Decimal('0.01')

price = Decimal('10')
number_of_product = Decimal('3')

price_per_product = price / number_of_product

# Round up the price to 2 decimals
# Here price_per_product = 3.33 
price_per_product = price_per_product.quantize(twoplaces)

remainder = price - (price_per_product * number_of_product)
# remainder = 0.01
```

I would like to know if there is a more pythonic way to do it, like for integer for example :

```
price = 10
number_of_product = 3

price_per_product = int(price / number_of_product)
# price_per_product = 3
remainder = price % number_of_product 
# remainder = 1
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to cents by multiplying your prices by 100, do all your math in cents, and then convert back.

```
price = 10
number_of_product = 3

price_cents = price * 100

price_per_product = int(price_cents / number_of_product) / 100
# price_per_product = 3
remainder = (price_cents % number_of_product) / 100
# remainder = 1
```

Then use Decimal to convert to strings.

Comment: Important keyword : integer!

Comment: I like it ! :) Thank you

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks to you I now have enough reputation to comment. :D